# Bind Param fails with empty variable

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
$query = "INSERT INTO api_fails (file, code, url, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ".time().")";

$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
if(!$stmt->prepare($query)) {
    echo("Failed to prepare statement.<br />\n");
} else {
    $file = $_GET['f'];
    $code = $_GET['c'];
    $url = $_GET['u'];
    $stmt->bind_param("sis", $file, $code, $url);
    if($stmt->execute()) {
        echo("Inserted.<br />\n");
    }else {
        echo("Didn't insert.<br />\n");
    }
}
```

I have found if any of the following variables are not set, the insert fails...

```
    $file = $_GET['f'];
    $code = $_GET['c'];
    $url = $_GET['u'];
```

How do I setup my insert so that if the variable isn't set it just inserts nothing into that field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just assign empty values to those variables if they are not set:

```
$file = (isset($_GET['f'])) ? $_GET['f'] : '' ;
$code = (isset($_GET['c'])) ? $_GET['c'] : '' ;
$url  = (isset($_GET['u'])) ? $_GET['u'] : '' ;
```

Comment: lol, wow that worked. I thought `''` would be the same as `null`, guess not. Thanks. I'll accept as soon as the 8 minutes are up and it lets me :) PS is there a better way to do this? Seems kind of limited if one of your variables is `null` the whole insert fails.

Comment: Yea actually I'm going to hold out a bit and see if someone has a more elegant solution. I have some big queries with 85 fields that need to be filled with data. I'd rather not make 85 more lines to set the variables to `''`.

Comment: Worst case I'll put all these insert statements into a function and set the default value of each parameter, which is still a huge hassle cause I can't pass an array of 85 values and instead I have to have a function with 85 parameters.