# INSERT INTO using SET and prepared statments

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
$query = "INSERT INTO api_fails SET file=?, code=?, url=?, date=".time().")";

$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
if(!$stmt->prepare($query)) {
    echo("Failed to prepare statement.<br />\n");
} else {
    $file = (isset($_GET['f'])) ? $_GET['f'] : '' ;
    $code = (isset($_GET['c'])) ? $_GET['c'] : '' ;
    $url  = (isset($_GET['u'])) ? $_GET['u'] : '' ;
    $stmt->bind_param("sis", $file, $code, $url);
    if($stmt->execute()) {
        echo("Inserted.<br />\n");
    }else {
        echo("Didn't insert.<br />\n");
    }
}
```

I get the following output:

`Failed to prepare statement.`

Comment: What data type is the date column?

Comment: @JohnConde it's a bigint(20). @mario SET works with `@mysql_query("INSERT INTO api_fails SET file = '', code = '', url = '', date = '".time()."'");`

Comment: [THat is a valid insert statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html)

Comment: There is an INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...

Comment: Didn't you just [`come from here?`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21470097/) not 20 mins. ago?

Comment: Ask `mysqli_error()` anyway. From your pre-edit comment it appeared there were backticks in the query before.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yea I'm figuring out this whole mysqli thing. running into some issues :(

Comment: @mario post a formal reply. `mysqli_error()` solved it. I had an extra ) at the end. "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1"

Comment: I take it that you used to have a working `mysql_` copy and you're trying to move over to `mysqli_`? @Rawr

Comment: well I'm trying to update my mysql queries. I'm finding it a bit frustrating esp cause if $file, $code, or $url aren't set then the whole query fails where the mysql_ would just insert a blank value in that field. I don't like that I have to make 3 more lines to solve it. Esp when I have big queries with 85 columns of data.

Comment: So, is it working for you now, and if not then what problem(s) are you now faced with? @Rawr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your working query I'd say your error is missing quotes around your date value:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO api_fails SET file=?, code=?, url=?, date='".time()."')";
```

Comment: close, very close. it's the ) at the end. `mysqli_error` found it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO api_fails SET file=?, code=?, url=?, date=?)";

    $stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
    if(!$stmt->prepare($query)) {
     echo("Failed to prepare statement.
\n");
    } else {
     $file = (isset($_GET['f'])) ? $_GET['f'] : '' ;
     $code = (isset($_GET['c'])) ? $_GET['c'] : '' ;
     $url  = (isset($_GET['u'])) ? $_GET['u'] : '' ;
     $time = time();
     $stmt->bind_param("sisi", $file, $code, $url,$time);
     if($stmt->execute()) {
         echo("Inserted.
\n");
     }else {
        echo("Didn't insert.
\n");
     }
    }
```